# jQuery ui selectable table to select/deselect checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface

I am trying to build a table grid which represents hourly blocks for each day of the week. What I would like to then do is make each cell in the table selectable, and to check a check box if that cell is selected, or if multiple cells are selected then tick all the check boxes that each cell corresponds to. I have put together a simplified version here: http://jsfiddle.net/yxAjx/4/.

I've really got as far as putting in the selectable code -

`$(function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable({
filter: ".block"
})
});`

For example if I clicked and dragged across the first 2 cells in the 'Tue' row I would want the corresponding check boxes to be checked.

The table that contains the check boxes I have no control over as this section of html is generated from the software I am using but I have replicated the lay out of it in my example.

My Javascript and jQuery knowledge is limited so would appreciate any pointers on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about doing something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable({
        filter: ".block",
        selected: function( event, ui ) {
            var row = $(ui.selected).parents('tr').index(),
                col = $(ui.selected).parents('td').index();
            $('#checks').find('tr').eq(row)
                        .children('td').eq(col)
                        .children('input').addClass('checked').prop('checked', true);
            $('#checks input:not(.checked)').prop('checked', false);
        },
        unselected: function( event, ui ) {
            var row = $(ui.unselected).parents('tr').index(),
                col = $(ui.unselected).parents('td').index();
            $('#checks').find('tr').eq(row)
                        .children('td').eq(col)
                        .children('input').removeClass('checked').prop('checked', false);
        }
    });

    $('#checks input').click(function(){
        var row = $(this).parents('tr').index(),
            col = $(this).parents('td').index();
        if($(this).prop('checked')){
             $('#selectable').find('tr').eq(row)
                        .children('td').eq(col)
                        .children('div').addClass('ui-selected');
        }else{
             $('#selectable').find('tr').eq(row)
                        .children('td').eq(col)
                        .children('div').removeClass('ui-selected');
        }
    });
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/yxAjx/9/

Comment: That's exactly what I was after and works perfectly with the full version. Thank you!